# Find a counter example for this.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of continuous functions which converges uniformly to $f$, proof: $f$ is continuous. The problem is not the question itself. We can proof it by methods like this [Uniformly continuous functions sequence $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to a uniformly continuous function $f(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663902/uniformly-continuous-functions-sequence-f-nx-converges-uniformly-to-a-unifor), but in the way I proof it. Let$$|f(x)-f(x_0)| \le |f(x)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|+|f_n(x_0)-f(x_0)|$$
Then I take the double limit on both sides. Which means, I let $x\to x_0, n\to +\infty$ **at the same time**. Then I claim that the right side becomes 0 and have finished the proof. But later I find something wrong. Consider the middle term on the right side. What do I mean by taking the limit is $$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists N>0,\delta>0, \ s.t.\ \forall n>N,|x-x_0|<\delta,\ we\ have\ |f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|<\varepsilon$$
But whether or not this limit exists can't be derived from uniformly convergence. Actually that is equicontinuity. I asked my teacher for this, but she disagreed with me. She said this limit did exist. But she didn't proof it and just said that I need to look at the book. I was trying to find a counter example which satifies the conditions above but doesn't have this kind of limit. But the conditions are too hard and too close to make it right. Can anyone help me?
One more important thing, if we take the limit like this: $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\lim_{x\to x_0} |f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|$$It should be equal to 0. But is not what I am talking about. What I am talking about is $$\lim\limits_{^{n \to +\infty}_{x \to x_0}} |f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)|$$

Comment: The problem is you haven't said what it means to "let $x\to x_0$ and $n\to \infty$ at the same time."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $|f_n(x)-f_n(x_0)| \leq |f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(x_0)|+|f(x_0)-f_n(x_0)|$. By continuity of $f$ at $x_0$ and uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ we can make each term less than $\epsilon /3$ by making $|x-x_0|$ small and $n$ large (not in any particular order).

Comment: Oh. You are right! Just the same method again. But this used the question itself. That's strange. This way uniformly convergence + continuous act like equicontinuity.